# How to keep specific element and remove others in json array?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have following json array:

```
[
 { "id": "1", "title": "Pharmacy", "desc": "xyz"},
 { "id": "21", "title": "Engineering", "desc": "xyz"},
 { "id": "30", "title": "Agriculture", "desc": "xyz"},
 ...
]
```

I want to keep only title element and remove other. I tried to solve this using php and javascript.

Comment: If you're going to keep only one property you might as well convert to just an array of strings: `["Pharmacy", "Engineering", "Agriculture", ...]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
 { "id": "1", "title": "Pharmacy", "desc": "xyz"},
 { "id": "21", "title": "Engineering", "desc": "xyz"},
 { "id": "30", "title": "Agriculture", "desc": "xyz"}
];

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  delete obj.id;
  delete obj.desc;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Or if you want to get an array of titles and keep the original array intact:

```js
var arr = [
 { "id": "1", "title": "Pharmacy", "desc": "xyz"},
 { "id": "21", "title": "Engineering", "desc": "xyz"},
 { "id": "30", "title": "Agriculture", "desc": "xyz"}
];

var titles = arr.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.title;
});

console.log(titles);
```

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let array = [
 { "id": "1", "title": "Pharmacy", "desc": "xyz"},
 { "id": "21", "title": "Engineering", "desc": "xyz"},
 { "id": "30", "title": "Agriculture", "desc": "xyz"}
];
let mapped = array.map(i => ({title: i.title}));

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solve it in PHP using:

```
$title = array();
foreach($arr as $val) {
  $json = json_decode($val, TRUE);
  $title[]['title'] = $json['title'];
}

$titleJson = json_encode($title);

var_dump($titleJson); //array of titles
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

```
$string = file_get_contents('yourjsonfile.json');
$json = json_decode($string,true); 

$title = [] ;
foreach($json as $t){
    $title[] =  $t['title'] ;
} 

var_dump($title);
```

if you don't have json file than you have use `json_encode` for creating json in php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function setArrayOnField($array,$fieldName){
  $returnArray = [];
  foreach ($array as $val) {
    $returnArray[] = [$fieldName=>$val[$fieldName]];
  }
  return $returnArray;
}
$list = [
  [ "id"=> "1", "title"=> "Pharmacy", "desc"=> "xyz"],
  [ "id"=> "2", "title"=> "Computer", "desc"=> "abc"],
  [ "id"=> "3", "title"=> "Other", "desc"=> "efg"]
];
print_r(setArrayOnField($list,'title'));
 ?>
```

**Try this code hope it's worth for you.**